# How to sum 2 text box in access 2013?

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010, ms-office, ms-access-2003

I have 3 text box calculated from 3 different columns.
like

> textbox1 data= (=sum([column]))
>
> textbox2 data= (=sum([column]))
>
> textbox3 data= (=sum([column]))

Now i want sum of all these 3 text boxes in a new field.

>
like textbox4 data should equal to (textbox1)+(textbox2)+(textbox3)

Last one is not formula or function i just mention here to explain how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=Sum((VAL(Textbox1))+(VAL(Textbox2))+(VAL(textbox3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as `ControlSource` for `textbox4`:

```
=Sum([column1])+Sum([column2])+Sum([column3])
```